# Algorithm for determining inside and outside regions of a 3D model (multiple meshes)

Tags: algorithm, mesh, region

I am trying to implement an efficient precomputed culling scheme in my 3D city model viewer program (a user can upload a 3D model of a city from any number of architecture programs, meaning that there can be a huge number of separate different unique meshes). And one major culling optimization that I would like to implement is culling out the interior of buildings when you are outside and culling out every other building when you are inside a model (this will help with frame rate, as I am running on an android device).

How would I algorithmically calculate what is the outside and what is the inside and then differeniate between the different interiors?

I was thinking if there was a way to pre calculate these regions, then during runtime it would be a simple position check against those small number of regions.

Comment: If you have a surface, you can distinguish between inside and outside with the direction of the normal. If you want to test points, you can cut the model with a line and count how many surfaces were pierced (odd or even).

Comment: @Sebastian the issue is that i have multiple meshes that make up a house (for instance each wall may be a different closed mesh). But I would like to calculate the overall inside/outside region enclosed by mutliple different meshes.

Comment: You can quickly isolate the different meshes by excluding any that do not have the point inside their bounding box. This is a pretty fast operation. Then you only have to worry about the one (or a couple close) mesh that you happen to be inside the bounding box of.

Comment: @corsiKa I guess I did not explain the question well enough. Imagine if you have a box where each side of the box was itself an enclosed box. such that the box made of boxes is not a single mesh (it is a super structure of a bunch of enclosed meshes). If i wanted to test if a point is inside the box of boxes. what algorithm would I use (remember the point is not inside any of the single box meshes, but it is inside the super structure that the meshes form)

Comment: Your house could have doors and windows or generally have holes in the walls => You could use a convex hull. This would not work well for L shaped houses. So instead you could do a projection and union in z direction - this would normally close houses except if they have no roof and open walls in the beginning. In that case you could apply an algorithm, which closes gaps in the walls up to a certain width.

Comment: @Sebastian that is interesting, now i need to figure our how to do a projection and union in z and find a way to close gaps :) Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: The projection is the easy part, first use the x and y coordinates and you get a 2D problem. Then take the union of the resulting shapes, because they would lie on top of each other.

Comment: But perhaps more simple would be, not to try to detect houses, but just find out, which surfaces face your viewer. Perhaps from different positions.